# IBM Watson IoT platform: Missing feature in device management framework?

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, ibm-watson

I am using device management framework of IBM Watson IoT platform. One of the key client requirements is that firmware should be installed (aka updated) in device as soon as it is downloaded. Currently I am not able to figure out a good way to fulfill that requirement using WIoTP.

That is I am not able to find a way in which my application will be notified by WIoTP when download completes on the device. I am left with polling using REST APIs, but that leaves some gap between download and update. In addition it creates an overhead. I tried subscribing to different MQTT topics mentioned [here](https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/applications/mqtt.html) for an application, but don't see any message coming in for device management statuses.

Basically am not able to find the feature of an app. being notified when a device completes download of firmware. Am I missing something or is the feature currently missing in WIoTP?

The only other way I think I can make this happen is for the device to publish download complete message to another topic. The application can then subscribe to this topic and get notified. But this is again a hack.

Comment: The documentation has some topics listed for subscribing for firmware update status.  https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/devices/device_mgmt/requests.html

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way other than the hack you suggest or polling.

Very shortly (days rather than weeks) there will be an update that allows you to pass `firmware/download` params in the `firmware/update` action.  This should solve your issue as there will be no need for polling between download and update.  The docs at the link mentioned by Valerie will be updated to reflect this when its available and there will be an update here:

http://status.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/

It could still be useful to be able to observe the communications between IoTP and the device using an API key, which would negate the need to poll for action completion.  If you would like to see such a feature please consider posting the idea here:

https://ibm-bluemix.uservoice.com/forums/311383-ibm-bluemix-ideas/category/131563-iot-services